# Optimizing Spring Boot REST controllers / Redundant request handler lookups

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, controller

We are working on optimizing some of our Spring Boot REST controllers and noticed a (relatively) large chunk of the time it takes to process a request is taken up by Spring looking for an appropriate mapping:

```
2018-08-15 16:55:10.869 DEBUG 66904 --- [nio-8080-exec-8]  o.s.b.w.s.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter [] [] : Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@63780123
2018-08-15 16:55:10.875 DEBUG 66904 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping [] [] : Looking up handler method for path /service/check_message
2018-08-15 16:55:10.890 DEBUG 66904 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping [] [] : Did not find handler method for [/service/check_message]
2018-08-15 16:55:10.891 DEBUG 66904 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] a.e.w.s.ControllerEndpointHandlerMapping [] [] : Looking up handler method for path /service/check_message
2018-08-15 16:55:10.891 DEBUG 66904 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] a.e.w.s.ControllerEndpointHandlerMapping [] [] : Did not find handler method for [/service/check_message]
2018-08-15 16:55:10.891 DEBUG 66904 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping [] [] : Looking up handler method for path /service/check_message
2018-08-15 16:55:10.891 DEBUG 66904 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping [] [] : Returning handler method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.infracast.ams.model.CheckResponse> com.infracast.ams.controller.CheckMessageController.messageCheck(com.infracast.ams.model.CheckRequest)]
2018-08-15 16:55:10.891 DEBUG 66904 --- [nio-8080-exec-8]     o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory [] [] : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'checkMessageController'
2018-08-15 16:55:10.892  INFO 66904 --- [nio-8080-exec-8]   com.infracast.ams.RequestLoggingFilter [] [DEV1] : POST /ams/service/check_message by 'DEV1'
```

The last line of the above logging is the first code that we've written.

Here's the controller that's being called:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/service/check_message")
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public class CheckMessageController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<CheckResponse> messageCheck(@RequestBody @Valid CheckRequest request) {
        ...
    }
}
```

What I'm interested in right now is how we can avoid Spring making 2 failed attempts to find the mapping using 'WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping' and 'ControllerEndpointHandlerMapping' as this would save ~15ms.

Comment: 15ms for `WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping` to check its mappings is a lot longer than I would expect. On my late 2013 MacBook Pro with 16 actuator endpoints exposed it takes 0-1ms.

Comment: I do have the worlds slowest i7 laptop but I was still surprised at how slow these calls are.